# Костыль в реализации динамической мультиязычности приложений на Qt

Tags: c++, qt5, multilanguage

Собственно, возник вопрос, обозначенный темой ...

Если брать стандартные примеры, где "язык приложения" грузится заранее - вопросов нет. С первоначальной одноразовой инициализацией проблем не возникает. Выполняем стандартные процедуры, инициализируем "транслятор" из внешнего файла или из ресурсов. Ноу проблемс!

А если нужно изменить "язык интерфейса" в рантайме? На сколько я разобрался, просто заменой "транслятора" это не решить. Нужно еще в каждый виджет добавить реализацию `changeEvent(QEvent* event)`, в котором переназначать "локализуемые" строки **КАЖДОГО** дочернего локализуемого компонента?

Вопрос - так это или нет? А если "нет", то как?

**Как вариант**

Мне это не нравится. Не нравятся "компилируемые" ресурсы переводов. Гораздо более юзабельнее иметь переводы в виде текстовых файлов с парами "ключ-значение". Что я и собираюсь реализовать.

**Любые мысли/предложения приветствуются!**

Comment: не вполне понятна проблема. можно какой-нибудь примерчик?

Comment: Кода примера уже нет, я его стер. Но на словах опишу. На диалоговой форме две кнопки "English" и "Russian". По нажатию выполняются слоты, которые подгружают соответствующие переводы. Так вот, пока я не реализовал обновление текстов на кнопках через `changeEvent(QEvent* event`, динамически названия кнопок не  обновлялись, хотя "трансляторы" подгружались и заменялись успешно. Просто хотел убедиться - и получил ответ ниже. Там все верно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переводы, не обязаны быть ресурсами. Вполне возможно использовать отдельные *.qm файлы. Просто в качестве первого аргумента [QTranslator::load](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#load) передаете путь к файлу.

Если вам не нравится *.qm как формат хранения данных (не текстовый?), то вы можете реализовать поддержку собственного, унаследовавшись от транслятора, и перекрыв функцию  [QTranslator::translate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#translate) см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018850/how-to-load-qtranslator-from-database .
Однако, пар ключ-значение недостаточно для больших проектов, поскольку одинаковые фразы в разных контекстах часто имеют разный перевод. Особенно это важно для коротких фраз и единичных слов (например, содержимое combobox-ов).

Реализация поддержки собственного формата переводов, не избавит вас от необходимости реализовать обработку события `changeEvent(QEvent* event)`. Суть в том что информация на виджеты может попадать не только из ui файла, но и формироваться динамически, поскольку отследить пути формирования динамического контента (в котором перевод осуществляется через [tr](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html), или `QCoreApplication::translate`) может только программист, то и обновление - задача программиста, а не автоматики. Для случая использования *.ui, достаточно вызвать `ui->retranslateUi`.

Не обязательно реализовывать `changeEvent(QEvent* event)` в каждом окне. Большинство окон - диалоговые, и событие смены языка не может произойти когда окно открыто (если только это не окно настроек программы). По сути, нужно обновить только: главное окно, диалог настроек, самописные виджеты (если они могут появляться  на главном окне или окне настроек).

Если вам лениво писать обработчик `changeEvent` в каждом виджете, можно использовать фильтр событий. но это применимо только если весь ваш интерфейс стротся на основе *.ui. (Т.е. почти никогда.) Примерно так:

```
template<typename Work>
class AutoEventFilter : public QObject
{
    // Q_OBJECT
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    {
        if(event->type()==eventType)
            work();
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj,event);
    }
    const int eventType;
    Work work;
public:
    AutoEventFilter(QObject*parent, int eventType, Work work)
        : QObject(parent), eventType(eventType), work(work)
    {щдз0
        installEventFilter(parent);
    }
};

template<typename Work>
QObject* autoEventFilter(QObject*parent, int eventType, Work work)
{
    return new AutoEventFilter<Work>(parent, eventType, work);
}

template<typename Widget, typename Ui>
void autoRetranslateUi(Widget*widget, Ui*ui)
{
    (void) autoEventFilter(widget, QEvent::LanguageChange, [=](){ ui->retranslateUi(widget); } );
}
```

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    autoRetranslateUi(this, ui);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мои опасения подтвердились. А `ui` я не использую никогда, не вижу смысла даже в диалогах. Ручками быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе пробежаться и сделать перевод "ручками" не сложно, хотя это и будет как в топике и обозначено "офигительный костыль"

```
void tr_object_tree(QObject* o, QString pr=""){
    foreach (QObject* child, o->children()) {
        qDebug()<<QString("%1 %2 (%3)").arg(pr).arg(child->objectName()).arg(child->metaObject()->className());
        if(child->metaObject()->className()=="QPushButton"){
            QPushButton* obj =qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(child);
            Q_ASSERT(obj!=NULL);
            if(!obj->property("original_label").isValid()) // чтобы можно было перевести на другой язык, надо сохранить "оригинал"
                obj->setProperty("original_label",obj->text());
            obj->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("main", obj->property("original_label").toString().toUtf8())); // или как вы это планировали - по своей базе ключ-значение
        }
        // QLabel, QComboBox,......
        tr_object_tree(child,pr+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант. Но в общем случае совсем не пойдет. У нас же куча виджетов, у которых не только `text` нужно менять. Например заголовок окна, у комбобокса элементы, подгрузка разных иконок, в зависимости от устанавливаемого языка & etc ... Похоже кроме как через реализацию `changeEvent(QEvent* event)` лучше не сделать, увы.